# parent/child binding does not work and binding target is set to object of unknown type

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a parent/child binding similar to what is described here
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt3.html

The first problem I am having is that the events appear to fire out of order thus the binding does not work.

The second problem is that the setter for the input property on my child component (commentList) is being called but it is being set to an object that is not of type ContentItem.  The object is not null, not undefined, and does not have a property named ID.

In a nutshell: The parent component calls a service.  Before the service returns, the setter in the child component is called and set to an object that is not the correct type (contentItem).  When the service returns in the parent and sets the Post object, the binding in the child should be updated but it is not.

Please see additional comments in the code below.

blogDetails (parent component)

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteSegment, OnActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BlogService} from './../services/BlogService';
import { SessionService} from './../services/SessionService';
import { ContentItem } from '../model/model';
import { CommentList } from '../comments/commentList';


@Component({
    selector: 'blog-blog-detail',
    templateUrl: './app/blog/blogDetail.html',
    directives:[CommentList]
})
export class BlogDetail implements OnActivate {
    PostRoot = this.sessionService.PostRoot;
    private Post: ContentItem;
    private Content: string;
    constructor(private sessionService: SessionService, private blogService: BlogService) {
        //this.Post = new ContentItem();
        this.Content = "";
    }

    routerOnActivate(data: RouteSegment)
    {
        let slug = data.getParam('slug');

        if (slug === null || typeof slug === 'undefined')
            return;

        this.blogService.GetContentItemBySlug(slug, this.sessionService.CurrentSite.ID).subscribe(x => { // this line fires first 
            this.Post = x;  // setting this should trigger the binding to update the child but it does not.

            this.blogService.GetPostHtml(this.sessionService.PostRoot + this.Post.URL).subscribe((h: string) => {
                this.Content = h;
            });    
        });
    }
}
```

blogDetail.html

```
<div>
    <h1>this is blog detail</h1>
    {{Post.Title }}
    <div [innerHTML]="[Content]"></div>
</div>
<blog-comment-list [contentItem]="Post"></blog-comment-list>
```

commentList (child component)

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteSegment, OnActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BlogService} from './../services/BlogService';
import { SessionService} from './../services/SessionService';
import { ContentItem } from '../model/model';
import { Comment } from '../model/model';

@Component({
    selector: 'blog-comment-list',
    templateUrl: './app/comments/commentList.html'
})
export class CommentList {
    private _contentItem: ContentItem;

    @Input()
    get contentItem()
    {
        return this._contentItem;
    }

    set contentItem(ci: ContentItem)
    {
        this._contentItem = ci;     // this line fires immediately after blogDetail calls GetContentItemBySlug... it should be called when POST is set
        this.LoadComments(this._contentItem)
    }
    Comments: Comment[];


    constructor(private sessionService: SessionService, private blogService: BlogService) {
        //this.Comments = [];

    }

    private LoadComments(ci: ContentItem) {

        if (ci === null || typeof ci === 'undefined' || ci.ID === 0)
            return;

        this.blogService.GetCommentsForContentItem(ci.ID).subscribe(x => {
            this.Comments = x;
        });
    }
}
```

commentList.html

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let comment of Comments">
        {{comment.CommentText}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you live and learn.  I discovered that newing up an object does not work quite the same way in Typescript as it does in c#.  Apparently object properties are not created when the object is created (this is strange...perhaps I should be initializing them to default values).  I set the ID to zero in the constructor so the child class would know not to try to call the api service.

```
export class BlogDetail implements OnActivate {
PostRoot = this.sessionService.PostRoot;
Post: ContentItem;
private Content: string;

constructor(private sessionService: SessionService, private blogService: BlogService) {
    this.Post = new ContentItem();
    this.Post.ID = 0;  // must initialize property or it will not be created on object
    this.Content = "";
}
```